# How to create path with sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the best solution :
I have a table in sqlserver with these contents .

```
PARENT CHILD  Level 
A        B      0
B        C      1
C        D      2
D        E      3
```

I need a query to create this result :
A/B/C/D/E

Comment: i am not sure about your result..would you please explain ?

Comment: I think there is no GROUP_CONCAT function in MSSQL.

Comment: I want to have a parent child relation in a row that sorted base on relation .

Comment: plz check this link,i think this is useful for you [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/818694/SQL-queries-to-manage-hierarchical-or-parent-child)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive CTE for this:

```
with cte as (
       select t.parent as p, t.parent as c, 0 as lev
       from table t
       where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.child = t.parent)
       union all
       select cte.p, t.child, lev + 1
       from cte join
            table t
            on cte.c = t.parent
     )
select stuff((select '/' + cte2.c
              from cte cte2
              where cte2.p = cte.p
              order by cte2.lev
              for xml path ('')
             ), 1, 1, '') as path
from cte
group by cte.p;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ce5f7/8) is a SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Use Coalesce to combine rows into single column separated by '/' delimiter

```
DECLARE @path VARCHAR(8000) = (SELECT parent FROM test WHERE LEVEL = 0)

SELECT @path = COALESCE(rtrim(@path) + '/', '') + child FROM test

SELECT @path
```

Comment: thnks @Konstantin for your suggestion, i had answered this as per original request which later on got changed.